# Why VNC performance seems to have dropped over the years?

Tags: vnc, remote-desktop

I've been using VNC since around 2000 (even earlier), back then I used a 19k cellular modem to connect to my desktop.
Lately I've been connecting to my Ubuntu desktop from my Android phone.
It seems to me that it works more slowly.

Why is that? I believe that the connection speeds increased much faster than resolutions (I'm on 1920x1080) and frame rates since then.
Am I underestimating the load that the higher resolutions add to the bandwidth required?
Could it be because back then I used TightVNC and now I'm using Vino?

Can something be done to make my remote X session bearable?

I read about other technologies (such as NX and SPICE) but from what I understood, they can only be used with separate X sessions and not to take over an existing one (did I miss an option that does).

Comment: If it is not bandwidth, and not a regression in the quality of the software, then it is probably latency. In fact latency often has a bigger affect on interactive performance than bandwidth. Modern cell phones using 3G/4G can have a higher latency than older 2G GSM (gsm had a dedicated low bandwidth timeslot, the newer systems share a much higher bandwidth, sometimes you have to wait for a slot). Also the position of your phone makes a huge difference to the bandwidth and latency.

Comment: The compressibility of the content as well makes a difference (gradients, images, animations...).

Comment: It's a conspiracy.  In 2000 a 4Mbps ADSL could blindingly fast load simple static pages, today it barely functions for these, and appears to be useless for anything more advanced.

Comment: The modem I used was a CDPD modem, that has really high latency.